# clone elements of a table to other

Tags: jquery

I have two tables and I want that when user clicks clone, the two dropdownlists are added in a single row (each one in a column).  I tried in so many ways but I can make it work, please help.

My js:

```
function initialize(){

$("#butonID").click(function (){
     var aux =  '<tr><td id="col-1"></td><td id="col-2"></td><td id="col-3"></td><td="col-4"></td></tr>';
    $('#tblSalida').append(
        $(aux).find('#col-1').append($('#prueba').clone().attr('id', 'nuevo').attr('class', '')).end()
    );
    $('#tblSalida').append(
        $(aux).find('#col-2').append($('#prueba2').clone().attr('id', 'nuevo').attr('class', '')).end()
    );

})
}
```

[Here's my code in action](http://jsfiddle.net/dETuG/23/)

**UPDATE**
modified the link

Comment: not sure but you cannot give ids starting with number ... somebody correct me if wrong

Comment: @3nigma: The [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#h-6.2) says you can't have an ID that starts with a number ;-)

Comment: @Rocket I modified the link again with others id, that not started by numbers, but that's not the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved my problem:

```js
$(document).ready(initialize);

function initialize() {

    $("#butonID").click(function() {
        $("#tblSalida").append('<tr></tr>');
        $("#tblSalida tr:last").append($('<td></td>').append($("#prueba").clone()));
        $("#tblSalida tr:last").append($('<td></td>').append($("#prueba2").clone()));
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select name="prueba" id="prueba" class="ddlStyles">
                <option value="">Elige un estilo</option>
                <option value="messageTextStyle1">Estilo 1</option>
                <option value="messageTextStyle2">Estilo 2</option>
                <option value="messageTextStyle3">Estilo 3</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select name="prueba" id="prueba2" class="ddlStyles">
                <option value="">Elige un estilo</option>
                <option value="messageTextStyle1">Estilo 1</option>
                <option value="messageTextStyle2">Estilo 2</option>
                <option value="messageTextStyle3">Estilo 3</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input name="primerboton" id="butonID" type="button" value="Copiar" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table id="tblSalida">
    <tr>
        <td>
            salida
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/dETuG/33/)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are appending the aux row to the #tblSalida table twice - ergo two rows.

modified your code a bit.

http://jsfiddle.net/hipstr/pKn7Y/1/

seems to work.

```
$("#butonID").click(function() {
    var aux = '<tr><td id="col-1"></td><td id="col-2"></td><td id="col-3"></td><td="col-4"></td></tr>';

    //append row 
    $('#tblSalida').append($(aux));


    // add clones to the row
    $('#col-1').append($('#prueba').clone().attr('id', 'nuevo').attr('class', '')).end();
    $('#col-2').append($('#prueba2').clone().attr('id', 'nuevo').attr('class', '')).end();
});
```

**Edit:**

Yes - this only works one time. You didn't specify in your question that you wanted multiple times.

To make it usable for multiple times you can't use ids like you do - you should use classes as ids are unique.

updated version 
http://jsfiddle.net/hipstr/pKn7Y/3/

```
$("#butonID").click(function (){
    var aux =  '<tr><td class="col-1"></td><td class="col-2"></td><td class="col-3"></td><td class="col-4"></td></tr>';

    //append row 
    $('#tblSalida').append($(aux));


    // add clones to the last row
    $('#tblSalida tr:last').find('.col-1').append($('#prueba').clone().attr('id', 'nuevo').attr('class', '')).end();
    $('#tblSalida tr:last').find('.col-2').append($('#prueba2').clone().attr('id', 'nuevo').attr('class', '')).end();

    });
```

**Notice:**

I have not really looked over your other code but it seems like you are copying two different ids #prueba and #prueba2 and cloning them to the same new id - 'nuevo'.

also - I'm not a jquery guru or anything and I don't know how :last selector works in different browser but that is at least a start.

But my advice is that you take care of id's uniqueness a bit more carefully

Answer (score 0):

you can do it this way

```
$(document).ready(initialize);

  function initialize(){

 $("#butonID").click(function (){

var aux =  '<tr><td id="col-1"></td><td id="col-2"></td><td id="col-3"></td><td="col-4"></td></tr>';

    $(aux)
    .find('#col-1').append($('#prueba')
    .clone().attr('id', 'nuevo').attr('class', '')).end()
    .find('#col-2').append($('#prueba2')
    .clone().attr('id', 'nuevo').attr('class', '')).end()
    .appendTo("#tblSalida");     
                })
            }
```

here is the demo http://jsfiddle.net/dETuG/30/